# Have Edits on Sidebar Show on All Pages

Tags: html, css, updates

Would it be possible for me to make edits on a particular item that is on all page on my website and have it be edited on all pages.

For example, if I had a sidebar on all pages of my website, and I wanted to change the announcements box within that sidebar to a new announcement, could I do so without having to make the changes on all pages? How would I be able to if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is an iframe, you'll find tons of tutorials about that, but here's a quick example:

In your page e.g. **index.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <iframe width="100" height="500" src="sidebar.html"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div>
        Your main page content
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In your **sidebar.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Sidebar content goes here...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now anything you update on the sidebar.html will be updated on index.html.

Add this iframe to every page that you want to contain this sidebar.

Hope this helps...

Comment: but wouldn't an iframe show to be a frame and not actually part of the website, or can I just remove borders and make it look like it's not even an iframe but a natural part of the website?

Comment: yes, you can adjust the style of the iframe the way you want, for instance `iframe { border:0; } would remove the borders.

Comment: is that better than server-side include? I noticed that mentioned in one of the similar sounding questions.

Comment: It depends on what you are after, with iframes you embed a whole separate page inside your page, you can use it to access pages not even on your website. If you use a server-side control e.g. asp.net user control (.ascx) you'll have access to all its properties and attributes, plus you can reuse it wherever you want. Hope this helped.

Comment: I'm looking to use this for the sidebar at www.ninjawarrior.info. Which would be the best option in that instance

Comment: what will be the content of the sidebar? is it dynamic content or static and is getting changed using html ?

Comment: it is simply text and images with one dropdown more button that I think may involve JavaScript. You can see it on www.ninjawarrior.info. I would just change certain bits of text

Comment: So it's static content, so no need for server-side code .. iframe is better for your case